# Change projection on geoTIFF file?

Tags: d3.js, geotiff

I would like to change the projection of a shadow relief geoTIFF file so that I can use it as a base for a D3 map.

The shadow relief map I would like to use is as follows:
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-gray-earth/

The D3 projection I would like to use is as follows
https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/jgnd8u45/

Can anybody show me how to do that? I basically want the relief map to appear underneath my D3 map. The base map should also be responsive to zoom and pan. Ideally when the projection has been 'sorted out' the TIFF should be converted to JPEG so it isn't as heavy lol `Thanks`

Comment: You can reproject in the browser ([example](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/6c940827c5f81c902d11c0cb3ecdf43a)), however it is not necessarily ideal for your purposes for a few reasons: limited re-sampling options and slow speed. I'd suggest reprojecting the image from a plate caree to a Mercator using a tool like QGIS/ArcMap and using that image in the visualization.

Comment: Andrew - that is the correct answer and I have already implemented it. Please feel free to paste below and shall accept.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a little bare as an answer here I think - it probably should have been more thorough as a comment (I think I was just heading off to bed when I wrote it).